# How to create a directory in memory? pseudo file system / virtual directory

Tags: java, file, filesystems

For my usecase, I would like to have an in memory directory to store some files for a very short time. Actually I compile source code to `.class` files at runtime, classload and execute them. The clean way would be to create a virtual directory and let the compiler create .class files there. Of course I *could* use a temp directory, but I have to clean it before compiling, I don't know if I'm the only one using it, etc.

So, is and how is it possible to create a virtual, in the meaning of in memory, directory in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 6 it is not really possible to do this kind of thing within a Java application.  You need to rely on the OS platform to provide the the pseudo-filesystem.

In Java 7, the NIO APIs have been extended to provide an API that allows you to define new file systems; see [`FileSystemProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html).

[Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html) is another option, but it has a couple of characteristics that may cause problems for existing code and (3rd-party) libraries:

- Files and directories in VFS are named using urls, not `File` objects.  So code that uses `File` for file manipulation won't work.
- `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, `FileReader` and `FileWriter` won't work with VFS for much the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could use a ramdisk. There are many apps out there that will do this, what you use would depend on the target OS.  I don't know of any *native* Java API that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is helpful or not, but do check [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html).

It seems that what you need is memory filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

For Java7's NIO there are

- https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem and
- http://exitcondition.alrubinger.com/2012/08/17/shrinkwrap-nio2/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [jimfs by Google](https://github.com/google/jimfs) as an in memory file system.
It looks like that would be what's needed here.

It's also very nice for unit/integration testing applications that interact with the filesystem.

Comment: If the question could be answered with a link or the name of something, it would be off-topic and should not be answered. If it is not asking for a link then answering it with a link is oonsidered a link-only answer and probably will be flagged as such and deleted. So, please either [edit] to turn this into an answer according to [answer] or delete this.