# Create a Java 7 zip FileSystem from an InputStream

Tags: java, zip, java-7

Java 7 introduced a zip FileSystem.  The link below illustrates how to create a zip FileSystem from a zip file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

However, I can find no example of how to create a zip FileSystem from an InputStream.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Note: I know I can write the InputStream to disk and create a zip FileSystem as described.  I consider that a hack, and I would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible because the file system requires random access to the ZIP file.

Shameless self-plug: You may find [TrueZIP](http://truezip.java.net) easier to work with and more powerful. However, the same constraint applies to it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer, but I expect you'll need a [custom file system provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html) and [this question about an in-memory file system might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508601/how-to-create-a-directory-in-memory-pseudo-file-system-virtual-directory). Note that the [newFileSystem documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#newFileSystem%28java.net.URI,%20java.util.Map%29) shows a `memory://...` URL scheme, but no more detail.

As pointed out in another answer, the file system requires bidirectional access to the data, so this assumes enough memory to load it entirely.