# In-memory only streaming of a zipped file

Tags: java, ftp, zip

Is it possible to retrieve a file from a FTP server that is zipped, and unzip it while it is streaming?

**This is being run in a cloud environment where I don't have access to the file system so it will be done all in-memory.**

I am using commons net ftp client's method: [`retrieveFileStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: What have you try? I guess wrapping your inputstream with a ZipInputStream should work: `new ZipInputStream(retrieveFileStream(...))`

Comment: Please read this thread, I think it answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030703/uncompressing-a-zip-file-in-memory-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You are using Apache's common library, and the method you are using returns InputStream, so you can wrap it in [ZipArchiveInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html) and read it as you like, as one may argue it's more reliable than the java.util.zip.* solution

If you didn't have access to Apache Commons, you could use [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to wrap your source InputStream.

Comment: So the Zip input stream takes care of the tokening etc. i.e. it knows when an entire row of the file has been streamed?  i.e. i want to loop through each line of the file and parse it.

Comment: @coolbreeze It only takes care of reading between EndOfFile markers. To parse file line by line you can read the file into buffer until End Of Line is encountered. Platform-independent EOL is represented as System.lineSeparator()